# Are questions like "Cat5e vs Cat 6" on topic?

Tags: discussion

Are they on topic? Should we make one big community wiki, about the different cat5(e)/6(a)/7?

Answer (score 9):

Questions need to be formed such that a definitive answer can be provided and accepted. So, "what are the differences between CAT 5e and CAT 6?" would not be appropriate. However, I think if it was rephrased as "I have an existing CAT 5e cable plant and want to from 100 Mbps to 1 Gbps. Do I need to upgrade to CAT 6?" then it would be acceptable (the answer would likely be something to the effect of "no, CAT 5e supports GigE because blah blah").

Comment: In other words, ask about specific problems you actually encounter in your day-to-day work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think so.

The answer I would expect would NOT be a simple "5e support 100mb and 6 supports gig" (or whatever it is) -- such answers should be down-voted as "too simple."

I would expect an explicit explanation of frequency differences, bandwidth, testing, bend radiuses, mutual-inductance, cross-talk, emmitted EMF, etc. The differences between Cat 5, 5e and 6 are NOT AT ALL simple.

Comment: Another alternative it to make a wiki about EACH cable. Instead of the comparisons?

Answer (score 2):

From the FAQ:

> Remember, you get the site you build! Ask difficult, specific questions — the kind of questions pros and experts ask each other, not the kind of questions novices ask pros, because a site full of pros and experts will attract everybody, but a site full of novices rapidly becomes boring. No easy questions, no survey questions, no polls, no intro-level/basic questions, no unanswerable hypothetical questions.

In my opinion, questions like "Cat5e vs. Cat 6" falls into the following categories:

- Easy question
- Intro-level/basic question

Not what I would expect to get out of a "Network Engineering" expert community.

Comment: That sounds a little too selective. You would think a professional sysadmin would know what the [different levels of RAID](http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them) are, yet that question is referenced often.

Comment: +1 to @r.tanner.f , we should not limit this to the most specialized questions. (this might also drive the mods insane ;))

Comment: We could make a community wiki? One answer, per cable, just to keep it all centralized. This could be used as reference everytime we might get "What is the difference"? or "Which to use?".